# separate nginx server blocks for same ports

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

nginx server blocks are defined as

```
server {
    listen 80;
```

We have a context where a series of `server_name` domains have their certificates issued on the server and wish to redirect them with

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

however, a few other domains are not going to have a certificate issued.  So the requirement is to listen to port 80 and redirect for a sub-set of domains while serving the others in plain http.

Should that be done with two nginx files, under Ubuntu 14.04, in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` or can this be syntactically done in a single file?

Comment: Use separate server blocks

Comment: OK.  so when a file is read, it will start at top or bottom and go through the whole file (i.e. pass through a block with no server_name), then continue reading, find another port 80 and execute it? No interrupts.

Comment: I don't get you. Probably you should read this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html and here really long and meticulous article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: You actually did understand me, as the first link was the proper article to point me to.